# Filter application run on Intellij like Android Logcat

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Recently I moved from Android development with Android Studio to back-end where I use Intellij 2021.3.

At AS "Logcat" there were two options, to filter logs by a filter which included regular expressions as well or to search in the logs by find.

Is there a way to have something similar to the filtering in "Run" tab of Intellij besides the find which is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not yet implemented in IntelliJ IDEA. Feel free to upvote for [IDEA-66268](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66268).

Comment: It was really handy when I used Android studio. Thanks